# Intercepting data from a longClick event in Android SDK

Tags: android, events

I want to get the details repeatably as long as the touchscreen is touched. 
I used `onLongClick` but it gets only a `View` without the event and it only occurs once.
Please help me to get these details.

Answer (score 0):

onLongClick is fired **after** the long-click happened.
You are probably looking for onTouch.

Comment: 10x, I am using both of them. The first touch is captured by onTouch and I get the event details. I want to deal with continues touch to get the continues data about the event, such as how did the size changed, the pressure and so on.

Comment: IMO there is no continuous touch. There a just loads of touch events fired one after another. However you may translate those into your own virtual continuous touch event.

Comment: Wow, how do you get them? Could you give a simple example? 10x

Comment: Take a look at the GestureDetector: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/GestureDetector.java

Comment: Hi, Tried that got to the same problem. I still can't get another event after getting the longPress event (while pressing down). Any other ideas?